# How to turn on led but turn off after program has started using arduino uno coding with IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a circuit with 2 proximity sensors, two leds and a toggle to start/end the program.

Sensor down (sD) turns on (ledB) and turns off (ledG) when activated.
Sensor up (sU) turns on (ledG) and turns off (ledB) when activated.

---

Context: 
The proximity sensors sence once a piston pump has reached end of stroke which will tell the arduino to switch a
solenoid valve in the other direction, reversing the direction of the pump. (leds represent solenoid for ease of
testing)

---

The Problem:
When the toggle is switched to the closed position and if the pump is mid stroke it wont move until the solenoid valve has 
been turned on and the pump reaches end of stroke which will activate a sensor starting the process. 
I need one led/solenoid valve to light up and then shut off as soon as one of the proxy sensors are activated.

---

Edit:
Video of what I have and what I'm trying to achieve:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15bgbLU_OcVZIzw9IDD_5R_cjSMGxHwGZ/view?usp=sharing

---

Thanks for any input...

This has me stumped

-Sam

```
int sD = 4;
int ledB = 2;
int ledG = 3;
int sU = 5;
int mainSwitch = 7;
int ledBin = 8;
int ledGin = 9;

void setup() 
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  pinMode(9, INPUT);
}

void loop() 
{

  mainSwitch = digitalRead(7);

  if (mainSwitch == true) //Ends Program
  {
    sD = digitalRead(4);
    sU = digitalRead(5);

    digitalWrite(ledB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledG, LOW);
  }


  if (mainSwitch == false)//Starts program 
  {
    sD = digitalRead(4);
    sU = digitalRead(5);

    if (sD == false) digitalWrite(ledB, HIGH); //sD(proximity sensor) Turns on ledB turns off ledG when activated
    if (sD == false) digitalWrite(ledG, LOW); 

    if (sU == false) digitalWrite(ledG, HIGH); //sU(poximity sensor) Turns on ledG turns off ledB when activated
    if (sU == false) digitalWrite(ledB, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot upload code files because you're supposed to provide relevant code sections in your text. please read [ask]

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to know. Can't you think of the logic to solve this or can't you translate that to code? Take pen and paper and write down any possible scenario and what you want to do in it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand

When you use digitalRead() on the Arduino it can return either "HIGH" or "LOW"

```
 if (sD == false)
 if (sU == false)
```

Try changing the "false" to "LOW" and see if that works for you.

Don't forget to check [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalread/) for more detailed info.

Comment: For historical reasons, digitalRead returns an int, which is either `HIGH (1)` or `LOW (0)`. So if you prefer, you can use bool variables and values as well.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need either one or the other LED (piston) active, while the main switch is ON. You change them at the end point, and you keep them unchanged, when no end point is reached.

On startup, you have to start with an arbitrary (or predefined) direction but not with both LEDs off, as you have it now. So there's not too much missing.

And don't confuse constant pin numbers and their variable states :)

```
const byte ledB = 2;
const byte ledG = 3;

// other pin numbers, hardcoded usage in code 
// sU = 5; sD = 4;
// mainSwitch = 7;

bool dir = true; // Direction:  default = up 

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(ledG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() 
{
  bool mainSwitch = digitalRead(7);
  if (mainSwitch == true) // stops Program
  {
    digitalWrite(ledB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledG, LOW);
  }
  else  
  {  // normal mode, one of both LED on
    // Read end switches 
    bool sD = digitalRead(4);
    bool sU = digitalRead(5);
    delay(5); // debounce, if these are mechanical switches

    if (sD) dir = true;  // switch to Up
    if (sU) dir = false; // switch to Down
    // else don't change direction

    if (dir) { 
      digitalWrite(ledG, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledB, HIGH);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(ledB, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledG, HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will turn on the ledG and not allow to switch to ledB unless the sU in continuously activated. @datafiddler

Comment: ledG is on (and ledB off), if (dir == false). `dir` changes to false when sU triggers. Normally (when neither SD nor sU is active) `dir` remains unchanged. Perhaps you need to exchange sD and sU.

Comment: Have solved this problem... you can look at my other post for the code if interested. @datafiddler

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own question thanks for the help.
-Sam

```
int sD = 4;
int ledB = 2;
int ledG = 3;
int sU = 5;
int mainSwitch = 7;
int ledBin = 8;
int ledGin = 9;

void setup() 
{

 pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(4, INPUT);
 pinMode(5, INPUT);
 pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(8, INPUT);
 pinMode(9, INPUT);
}

void loop() 
{

 mainSwitch = digitalRead(7);

 if (mainSwitch == true) //Ends Program
  {
   sD = digitalRead(4);
   sU = digitalRead(5);

   digitalWrite(ledB, LOW);
   digitalWrite(ledG, LOW);
  }


 if (mainSwitch == false)//Starts program 
 {
  sU = digitalRead(5);
  sD = digitalRead(4);

  if (sU == HIGH) //Turns on ledG(down solenoid) at first start. sU(upper 
  sensor) in deactivated
  {
   ledGin = digitalRead(9);
   ledBin = digitalRead(8);

   if (ledBin == LOW)digitalWrite(ledG, HIGH);
  }

 else if (sU == LOW) //sU(upper sensor) is activated turning on ledB(down 
 solenoid) turning off ledG(up solenoid)
 {
  ledBin = digitalRead(8);
  ledGin = digitalRead(9);

  if (ledBin == LOW) digitalWrite(ledB, HIGH);//ledB(down solenoid) turn on
  if (ledGin == HIGH) digitalWrite(ledG, LOW);//ledG(up solenoid) turn off
 }

if (sD == LOW)//sD(Bottom sensor) is activated turning on ledB(down 
solenoid) turning off ledG(down solenoid)
 {
  ledBin = digitalRead(8);
  ledGin = digitalRead(9);

  if (ledBin == HIGH) digitalWrite(ledB, LOW);//ledB(down solenoid) turn off
  if (ledGin == LOW) digitalWrite(ledG, HIGH);//ledB(up solenoid) turn on
 }
}
}.
```